# Multiple pages requiring auto refresh with different options saved on each

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, cookies, fragment-identifier

I am currently working on a project where the user lands on a page to build custom looping maps. When the user picks the type of map, a new browser tab (this is directed to happen, I have no say in the matter) opens with that particular map looper. There are controls for speed, start and stop times, and a checkbox to enable a 15 minute auto refresh. Currently, I use JQuery to capture the dropdowns and checkbox, save the values to a cookie, and then load those back when the page refreshes.

This obviously works fine, except that in meteorology, I may need two maps open and looping. Sometimes even more. If I use cookies, that second map will use the values as the first. If I change the options for the second map, the first one will refresh with those options. This is not ideal.

I see sessions and cookies the same. If I am opening tabs, those values will persist through each map looper. My other option is maybe use a hashtag on the URL and keep the values selected there and parse that back in on the refresh. Am I missing something? I would rather not use hashtags because it seems messy, but I cannot figure out how to have multiple tabs using different values within the cookie. What if the user has 10 tabs open? My question is, for this application, which is the best solution to implement?

We utilize javascript/JQuery and php within the pages. Our product must be compatible with Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Comment: Can you use session variables server side, assign a session id to each "page/tab" as it is loaded and relate that unique id to the cookie creation?

Answer (score 0):

Prepend a unique id to the cookie data that matches an individual map. So option1 on map2 becomes map2option1

Answer (score 0):

By tab you mean webbrowser tab or just div on the same page?
If your tabs are elements on one page just decorate them with uniq data

```
<div class="mytab" data-session="1">
//tab data
</div>
<div class="mytab" data-session="2">
//tab data
</div>
```

when you refreash data:

```
$('.mytab[data-session]').each(function(){
   $.post('/refres', { sessionId : $(this).data('session')}, function(html){
      $(this).html(html);
   })
});
```

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. It should be browser tabs. Depending on the user, when they hit the build product button on the landing page, they either get a browser tab or new window. I will edit my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use new tabs on every tab create hidden session key

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()" id="sessionKey" />
```

on refresh and save pass it to controller. It is hidden for user